# QGIS Converting simple PNG raster file yields "warning 1: model file not specified"

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

I have GQIS 3.28.14 Firenze on a Mac (12.7.1.Monterey). I want to convert a simple PNG file (30 KB) with county boundaries into a vector file through the QGIS commands: Raster >  Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to Vector). In some youtube clips this is achieved successfully with apparently more complex raster files. However, I receive repeatedly the error message

```
"Warning 1: Model file not specified.
Creating output /private/var/folders/ym/vctv4q6d667fnvpcvh_vk03m0000gn/T/processing_OoBBBC/9f3aeeaffdbd44a38f03606f86a3856d/OUTPUT.xtf of format Interlis 2."
```

Comment: I do not know why QGIS is suggesting Interlis as the output format for you. For me it gives GeoPackage by default. Or did you select the format yourself? Interlis raquires a model file https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/ili.html. Open the "Vectorized" menu item and select for example just GeoPackage format for the output and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not edited the "vectorized" menu item, expecting it would be saved by default into a temporary layer. Your advice worked perfectly. For whatever reasons the output file shows the graph upside down. But I trust I will find a way to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Default output vector layer extension (in Settings->Options->Processing->General) to a value other than "xtf" e.g. to the value "gpkg" which is the default for such option.